# How does one use SSDT to define a stored procedure which has a table-valued parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

My project is using VS 2012 and SSDT for SQL Server 2012.   We are using SSDT to publish a database straight from VS.

I would like to define a custom table type and a stored procedure which uses that custom table type.  However, SSDT will not let me define the table type and the stored procedure in one file.

How does one define a custom table type in SSDT so that it will be deployed ahead of any stored procedures which use that custom type?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in one file? A table type does not belong to a stored procedure; it can be used by many procedures, just like any user tables, views, UDFs, etc. that are mentioned in the stored procedure. You don't need to deploy the tables or views as part of the stored procedure script file, right? Are you certain that - if you script them as separate files - SSDT won't be smart enough to deploy the table type first? I suspect that it will, and if it doesn't, that's probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

SSDT is indeed smart enough to order the type in the publish script before the sproc.  Therefore, there was no need to worry about their being in separate files.

Turned out to be pretty neat.